# Bind JSON from R script to Plotly chart

Tags: asp.net, json, r, plotly, sql-server-2017

I need to get the results from an R script, which returns JSON, and render that as a Plotly Chart in a web browser using the plotly.js. The R script also uses Plotly but is uploaded to a SQL Server 2017 Enterprise. I am calling a SQL Stored Proc which in turn executes the R script from an asp.net MVC controller and returning the data to the browser. The R Script was developed by someone else and the returned JSON has the chart layout and data all in one JSON object. The following doesn't work. It just renders a blank chart with X and Y axis but none of the data.

```
var data;

$.ajax({
    url: 'GetPlotlyPOCData',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json;',
    success: function (returnedData) {
        data = returnedData;

        Plotly.newPlot('plotlyVisDat', data);
    }
});
```

plotlyVisDat is the ID of a div on the page.

Comment: Could you share more of the code - how the controller calls the stored procedure, what the procedure looks like, etc. Also, have you verified that in your code above, there is data in the `returnedData` parameter?

Comment: Yes, I am using Google Chrome dev tools and I put a breakpoint in to confirm that the data is returned. I think the problem is that the R programmer is returning more than just the chart data. It also contains the layout specifications as well and maybe this newPlot function doesn't expect that. I am not sure as I am new to this js library and R. I will add controller code in just a moment.